# Is it more efficient to slice an array or use Iterator::skip?

Tags: arrays, vector, rust, monads, slice

I want to call a function for each element in a slice `[0+k .. n]`, where `k` is an offset and `n` is the number of elements in the vector. Importantly, I want the index of the element from the original slice.

I have found two ways of doing this:

1. Use `enumerate` and `skip` the beginning items

   ```
   vec.iter().enumerate().skip(k).map(|(i, v)| (f(v), i)).min()
   ```
2. Take a subslice and add the offset to the index from `enumerate

   ```
   vec[k..].iter().enumerate().map(|(i, v)| (f(v), i + k)).min()
   ```

In both cases, `vec` is a vector of strings, and `f` returns a specific character in the string (`v.chars().nth(offset)`). Which of these solutions is most efficient?

Comment: I'd always prefer slicing over `skip`, even if with the specialization of skip (via nth). Profiling will tell you the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's use this code as an example. It's similar to your example, but a bit simpler:

```
fn main() {
    let items = ["a", "bb", "ccc", "dddd", "eeeee"];
    let k = 3;

    let one = items.iter().enumerate().skip(k).map(|(i, v)| (v.len(), i));
    let two = items[k..].iter().enumerate().map(|(i, v)| (v.len(), i + k));

    // Sanity check that the results are the same
    let items1: Vec<_> = one.collect();
    let items2: Vec<_> = two.collect();

    println!("{}", items1 == items2);
}
```

Which will be more performant is a tricky topic. Rust and LLVM have good optimizations that can make code quite fast.

Based purely on my *gut feeling*, I would probably use the first one if I knew that I was going to skip just "a few" of the items, and the second one if I didn't know how many or if it were a lot.

In the first case, you conceptually have to iterate through all of the items that you want to skip over. It is possible that the optimizer could reduce this down, but it's complicated by the interaction with `enumerate` and `map`, so I wouldn't count on it without inspecting assembly.

The second one (`items[k..]`) uses subslicing, which will be an O(1) operation as it's simply going to index into a chunk of memory. Then you do addition which will also be simple.

However, the only true test is to do some profiling. We will create a large input array and start part way:

```
fn main() {
    let items = ["a", "bb", "ccc", "dddd", "eeeee"];
    let items: Vec<_> = items.iter().cycle().take(10_000_000).collect();

    let k = 371_223;

    // let one = items.iter().enumerate().skip(k).map(|(i, v)| (v.len(), i));
    let two = items[k..].iter().enumerate().map(|(i, v)| (v.len(), i + k));

    // let items1: Vec<_> = one.collect();
    let items2: Vec<_> = two.collect();

    // println!("{}", items1.len());
    println!("{}", items2.len());
}
```

Running that code, compiled with optimizations, has the following times averaged over 10 runs:

1. 153.6ms
2. 160.1ms

So, contrary to what my *gut feeling* said, the first version is faster. It's entirely possible that my benchmarking is incorrect, but that's why you should do benchmarking on your real code.

Also, note that this is *really fast* either way. That's about 15 or 16 **nanoseconds** per item. What's one nanosecond among friends?

Comment: FWIW, `cargo bench` results with opt-level 3 for the second one (with k=371_223 and 10mil items): 

bench_skip  ... bench:  67,159,746 ns/iter (+/- 4,175,973)

bench_slice ... bench:  67,355,711 ns/iter (+/- 3,690,489)

Source file for reference

https://gist.github.com/Jragonmiris/e52173ba5b0e8c9c3c69